# Generate Xtrareport

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I want to generate dynamic table in Xtrareport in a proper format.

So I am using this code

```
   dynamicTable.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All

        dynamicTable.BorderWidth = 1
```

But it is not giving proper output as I desire..

It is generating table by separating each cell row by row, so it doesn't give a table appearance.!

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaKl9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaKl9.png)

The complete code:

```
 Dim label As New XRLabel()
    label.Width = 500
    label.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 10.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
    PageHeader1.Controls.Add(label)

    If rowsCount > 0 Then
        Dim padding As Integer = 5
        Dim tableWidth As Integer = Me.PageWidth - Me.Margins.Left - Me.Margins.Right - padding * 2

        Dim dynamicTable As XRTable = XRTable.CreateTable(New Rectangle(padding, 1, tableWidth, 40), 1, 0) ' table column count

        dynamicTable.Width = tableWidth
        dynamicTable.Rows.FirstRow.Width = tableWidth
        dynamicTable.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All
        'dynamicTable.Borders = DirectCast(((DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Left Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Top) Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Right) Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Bottom, DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide)
        dynamicTable.BorderWidth = 1
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        dynamicTable.BeginInit()
        For Each dc As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns

            Dim cell As New XRTableCell()

            Dim binding As New XRBinding("Text", ds, ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName)
            cell.DataBindings.Add(binding)
            cell.CanGrow = False
            cell.CanShrink = True
            cell.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.MiddleCenter
            'cell.WidthF = 10 
            'cell.Width = 20
            cell.Text = dc.ColumnName
            dynamicTable.Rows.FirstRow.Cells.Add(cell)



            i += 1

        Next dc


        dynamicTable.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.0F)
        dynamicTable.AdjustSize()
        dynamicTable.EndInit()
        Detail.Controls.Add(dynamicTable)
        'label.Text = String.Format("Data table: {0}", Test)

        Me.DataSource = ds
        Me.DataMember = Test
```

Comment: what is the layout of you report and how do you want to place this dynamic table??? your question does not have complete information that what have you tried and what are you exactly doing??? if possible attach some snapshot for such kind of layout problem.

Comment: could you provide more relevant code that how are you creating table and it's style??